# at command: Exec failed for mail command: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, scheduled-task, at

I got to run a task today at midnight on a debian system.

As I never did anything with atd I wanted to try first, if it works as expected.

I got a `test.sh` in folder `/usr/local/dump/`
which contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "xyz" > out.file
```

I try to execute the shell script by the following:

```
/usr/local/ecs_dump$ at 12:46
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> test.sh
at> <EOT>
job 20 at Tue Jun  7 12:46:00 2016
```

When I check the syslog, I keep getting:

```
Exec failed for mail command: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone explain me, what I did wrong here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need mail command. It is used to send mails with the output of the at scripts. You can install `s-nail` package which provides this command:

```
apt-get install s-nail
```